# Convert a sequence of arrays T myArray[] to IEnumerable<T> in c#

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

In the following code I want to return an IEnumerable without creating a new data structure object. However, I get a compiler error with the following code. What am I missing?

```
Error       Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo[]' to 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' 

public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(Type objectType)
{
   while (objectType != null)
   {
      //GetFields(...) returns a FieldInfo []
      yield return objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
      objectType = objectType.BaseType;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type.GetFields returns an array of FieldInfo objects.

Since you´re not returning a collection of arrays, you have to iterate over the array and yield return each object in it, kinda like this:

```
foreach (var fi in objectType.GetFields(...))
    yield return fi;
```

Answer (score 4):

`yield return` operates on single elements; you can simply return the return value from `GetFields` to achieve what you want.

To explain further, `yield return` is mainly useful when you want to apply some operation to each item in a sequence before making it available to the caller, but *you don't want to do all of that work up-front* and simply return the aggregate results in an array or `List<T>`.

`yield return` makes this *deferred execution* easy to write, because the generated iterator block only applies any such operation to each item as it's requested.

EDIT: Sorry - I missed one of the points of your code (enumerating the base fields), but I'll leave this answer up since I think it might be useful anyway. Lasse Karlsen's answer will do what you need, but unless you have a huge type hierarchy, you're not really gaining any advantage over just aggregating the results and returning them in an array.

Comment: but that will not enumerate the base fields.

Comment: What if DeclaredOnly is not used, would it do it then? I´m not at my computer now and my iPad doesn´t run .NET code so I can´t check.

Comment: Use BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy (from memory, might be a little different)

Comment: GetFields(...) has a "feature" where private fields of base classes are not returned. This is my work around.

Answer (score 1):

You can try recursion + `Concat`:

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(Type objectType)
{
   if (objectType == null)
      return Enumerable<FieldInfo>.Empty;
   else 
      return objectType.GetFields(
                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public |
                 BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
         .Concat(GetAllFields(objectType.BaseType));
}
```

Comment: I like this solution the best, but I see my real issue was trying to use the yield keyword on an entire array.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a "yield forall."  You'd have to foreach through and yield return each item returned from GetFields and then set to the base class.

This shouldn't be necessary though because there is a flag for whether or not to include base-class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

How about a little recursion?

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(Type objectType)
{      
      //GetFields(...) returns a FieldInfo []
      var fields = objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
      if(objectType.BaseType==null) return fields;
      return fields.Concat(GetAllFields(object.BaseType));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As everybody pointed out, the issue is that the type of the element yielded doesn't match with the type expected.

To avoid writing a for/while/foreach every time, I like to use an extension method that handles the iteration for me.

```
public static class Sequence
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Create<T>(T seed, Func<T, bool> predicate, Func<T, T> next)
    {
        for (T t = seed; predicate(t); t = next(t))
            yield return t;
    }
}
```

That way, you can return the fields writing a much more readable query

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(Type objectType)
{
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
    return from type in Sequence.Create(objectType, t => t != null, t => t.BaseType)
        from field in type.GetFields(flags)
        select field;
}
```